# Could not resolve dependency jasmine-core on app creation

Tags: angular, npm

Im trying to create new project in angular with 'PowerShell' ,and im getting this:

[image: The 'PowerShell']

I've been looking around here (in SOF) And I didn't find any help, please help me solve the problem and create a Angular project.

EDIT:
And That's the message I got now:
[image]

Comment: Look the post now plz ,its ok now?

Comment: Well, you tell us! But looks ok to me, I don't see any more errors... The CRLF is just a warning as you are on Windows.

Comment: So ok ,thank u so mutch!